# How to use TreeView for .NET?

Tags: .net, treeview, controls, nodes, delphi-prism

Coming from Win32, I am having bit of an issue or a problem trying to work with treeview for .NET. I have searched online, msdn library and stackoverflow and none seem to help me.

Could someone, please, show me how you can use Treeview to create node, create childnode, set data or object, retrieve object, check its level, etc...

Example code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @ Anna Lear , Winform is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create a root Node

use the [`Nodes.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.add%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add('A Node');
```

2) Create a Child Node, get the instance to the parent node  and uses the [`Nodes.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.add%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
Node.Nodes.Add('A Child Node');
```

3) To store an object in anode use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property of the Node

```
Node.Tag:=MyObj;
```

4) To Retrieve the object use the tag property and cast the value.

```
MyObj2:= TMyObject(Node.Tag);
```

5) to get the level, chek the [`Level`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.level%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property of the node.

Check this simple code :

```
Var
  Node     : TreeNode;  
  MyObj    : TMyObject; 
  MyObj2   : TMyObject; 
begin
  Node:=treeView1.Nodes.Add('A Node'); //add a root node 
  Node.Text:= String.Format('{0} in level {1}',Node.Text,Node.Level);

    Node.Nodes.Add('A Child Node');
    Node.Nodes.Add('Another Child Node');
  Node:=treeView1.Nodes.Add('Another Node');

  MyObj:=New TMyObject;
  MyObj.Foo:='Hello';
  Node.Tag:=MyObj;//set the object



  MyObj2:= TMyObject(Node.Tag); //get the assigned object
  MessageBox.Show(MyObj2.Foo);

end;
```

Comment: Great answer. How do you find the first node if I may ask? In C# there is FirstNode property, but I don't see that option in Delphi Prism.

Comment: All the  properties present in C# exist in Delphi prism, remember which C# and Delphi Prism (and all the .Net languages) uses the same framework. the [FirstNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.firstnode%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is part of each node (TreeNode) so you can acees this propertie like so `Node.FirstNode`.